# RenderSection() issue in _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have following code snipped in _Layout.cshtml

```
<div id="sub-navig-container">
    @RenderSection("subNavig")
</div>

<div id="text-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

when i add in my view

```
@section subNavig
{
    //some code
}
```

it is work good, but when I write this in _ViewStart I have an error:
**The name 'DefineSection' does not exist in the current context**
[image]

Please explain  why, and if possible tell how can I fixing this issue

Answer (score 23, accepted):

_ViewStart is a special view which derives from `ViewStartPage` instead of `WebViewPage` which other views derive from. And the `ViewStartPage` class doesn't have a `DefineSection` method. So you cannot define sections in this file. You could provide default contents to this section in the layout directly:

```
<div id="sub-navig-container">
    @if (!IsSectionDefined("subNavig"))
    {
        // some default code
    }
    else
    {
        // render the code that was overridden in the child view
        @RenderSection("subNavig")
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say if RenderSection is defined in ViewStart class then how the Razor view engine become aware about the section you are rendering? RenderSection are by design only consume sections defined immediately by the view using them. Since ViewStart runs before any view requested code runs, this is why it is not avaialble there.

This is by design. Currently Razor layouts can only consume (render) sections defined immediately by the view using them. You cannot have a hierarchy of layout pages and in the outermost layout consume a section defined in the innermost view.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1623650.aspx/1